# Checking if a piecewise defined function in two variables is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

How would I check if the following function is continuous?

$$
f(x, y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} & \text{, if } x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\\
    0 & \text{, otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

I have a hunch that it *is* continuous, but have no idea how to proceed. Which limit (if any) should I calculate and determine its existence / value? I could not find anything in either my book or my notes, and a Google search turned out fruitless.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you realised that at every point except those in the unit circle it is continuous and that you need to check what happens at those points?

Comment: I do realize that, yes (that's where my “hunch” comes from), but how do I check for every point along the circumference of the unit circle? If $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then $f(x, y) = 0$, but what limit value do I compare this to?

Comment: Let $C$ be the unit circumference and take $(x_0, y_0)\in C$. You should check if $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (x_0, y_0)}(f(x,y))=f(x_0,y_0)$ or not. The same must be proved (it suffices to mention it really) for $(x_0, y_0)\in \mathbb R^2\setminus C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a substitution to polar coordinates and let $r\to1$.

Comment: If you're experiencing trouble making the substitution, let me know and I'll make an edit...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would seem that my assumption was correct!